# Migrated Database from SQL Server CE to Express using WebMatrix - now I cannot find the physical database

Tags: sql-server, migration, sql-server-ce, sql-server-express, webmatrix

I have migrated my SQL Server to SQL Server Express using the method described [here](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/migrate-a-database-to-sql-server). I have since tried to send on the website to some friends for testing and the database has been missing from my compression.

When I open the website folder in WebMatrix, it loads it, and the database, perfectly. However, trying to locate the physical SQL express database so I can forward it on has proven fruitless. So, I apologise for the silly question, but...where can I find my database?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your setup, but here's where it shows up for me, which should help you find it on your machine...

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA